# Pass markdown files to Vue component through router

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vue-router, vue-router4

I'm using VueJS. I have externally generated markdowns, and I want to generate static pages out of them thanks to a vue component. I'm using the `vite-plugin-md` to convert imported md files into a component.

#### Working example

Config (`vite.config.js`)

```
import Markdown from "vite-plugin-vue-markdown"
```

The router (`index.ts`)

```
  {
    path: "/my_page_1",
    name: "My Page 1",
    component: () => import("@/pages/markdown.vue"),
  }
```

The component (`markdown.vue`)

```
<template>
  <MardownPage/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import MardownPage from "@/assets/markdown/my_page_1.md"
</script>
```

#### Expected behavior

In the working example, the component is tied to a unique markdown.

I actually want to use the same component for many different markdown pages. I feel the expected way to do this is to have something like the following in the router :

```
  {
    path: "/my_page_1",
    name: "My Page 1",
    component: () => import("@/pages/markdown.vue"),
    meta: {
      path: "@/assets/markdown/page_1.md",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/my_page_2",
    name: "My Page 2",
    component: () => import("@/pages/markdown.vue"),
    meta: {
      path: "@/assets/markdown/page_2.md",
    },
  }
```

#### Current (non-working) behavior

On the component side, I've written the following

```
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const route = useRoute();

console.log(route.meta.path);

const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import(route.meta.path)
)
```

While the path appears in the console, it does return an error related to the dynamic importation of the module (`error loading dynamically imported module`).

I've tested many options related to lazy loading, dynamic routes, promises, ... (which I'm not 100% familiar and skilled with) but haven't worked my way around to do so.

Comment: `import {MardownPage} from route.meta.path` - JS imports don't work this way, not to mention that you need to be aware what "script setup" syntax actually does. It possibly could be something like `const MardownPage = import(route.meta.path)`. But could be just `component: () => import("@/assets/markdown/my_page_1.md")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you currently have and what you described as the desired output, I would suggest starting at looking at `defineAsyncComponent`. This function needs to be provided with a resolved promised. You are currently attempting to run import dynamically at runtime & it might also have something to do with aliases in your path.

I setup the following project:

vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Markdown from 'vite-plugin-vue-markdown'
import path from 'node:path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      include: [/\.vue$/, /\.md$/],
    }),
    Markdown(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
    }
  }
})
```

src/router/index.ts

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    // ...
    {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'test',
      component: () => import('@/views/MarkdownView.vue'),
      meta: {
        path: 'components/Test.md',
        markdownComponent: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('components/Test.md'))
      },
    }
  ]
})
```

src/views/MarkdownView.vue

```js
<template>
    <AsyncMarkdown />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute()

console.log(route.meta.path) // components/Test.md

// DOES NOT WORK
const AsyncMarkdown = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(route.meta.path))

// WORKS
const AsyncMarkdown = route.meta.markdownComponent
</script>
```

If I change the `route.meta.path` to the relative path `../components/Test.md`, it will then load the component.

### Possible Solutions

1. Load the `defineAsyncComponent()` in your router
2. Add the full/relative path without alias to the `route.meta.page` variable.